# How to send OPA Decision Logs to OpenTelemetry

Tags: logging, opa, otel

I would like to send all the Decision Logs from an OPA server to AWS CloudWatch, using an OpenTelemetry collector.

Is there any support for this in the Open Policy Agent, or are there any examples of doing this? I see OPA can be extended with custom plugins.

Decision Logs: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management-decision-logs/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.